# UI Unresponsive when we jquery ajax abort called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am doing a four API calls(for twitter,facebook,instagram,youtube) on selecting brand name and get data and set the response to different div.

[image]

When if i select first brand say "ford" and request made by using ajax asynchronous call, on between request if i select other brand,then previous made request is aborted and second one get processed.

First Ajax calls is aborted and second request was run but between abort process,my dropdown box get unresponsive until all request get aborted.

**Sample code :**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var cblcurrentRequest = null;
    var currentRequest = null;
    var twcurrentRequest = null;
    var fbcurrentRequest = null;
    var igcurrentRequest = null;
    var ytcurrentRequest = null;

    var firsttwcurrentRequest = null;
    var firstfbcurrentRequest = null;
    var firstigcurrentRequest = null;
    var firstytcurrentRequest = null;

    load_session();//load access key on session

    $('#brands').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#selcategory').change(function () {


        $('.loader_cmn').show();
        $("#brands").select2("val", null);
        $('#brands').append('<option value=" ">Select Brand Name</option>');
        $('#brands').prop('disabled', true);

        var categoryID = this.value;

        if (categoryID != "") {
            currentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'admin/Adminhome/getCategoryListByIdWithLogin/' + categoryID, type: 'post', data: '',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    var msg = "<center><b>Please select brand</b></center>";
                    $('#tw').html(msg);
                    $('#fb').html(msg);
                    $('#inst').html(msg);
                    $('#yt').html(msg);
                    hide_loader();
                    if (currentRequest != null) {
                        currentRequest.abort();
                    }

                    if (twcurrentRequest != null) {
                        twcurrentRequest.abort();
                    }
                    if (fbcurrentRequest != null) {
                        fbcurrentRequest.abort();
                    }
                    if (igcurrentRequest != null) {
                        igcurrentRequest.abort();
                    }
                    if (ytcurrentRequest != null) {
                        ytcurrentRequest.abort();
                    }
                    if (firsttwcurrentRequest != null) {
                        firsttwcurrentRequest.abort();
                    }
                    if (firstfbcurrentRequest != null) {
                        firstfbcurrentRequest.abort();
                    }
                    if (firstigcurrentRequest != null) {
                        firstigcurrentRequest.abort();
                    }
                    if (firstytcurrentRequest != null) {
                        firstytcurrentRequest.abort();
                    }

                }
            }).done(function (res)
            {
                $("#brands").empty();
                $('#brands').append('<option value="" selected="">Select Brand Name</option>');
                var obj = JSON.parse(res);
                $.each(obj, function (i, item) {
                    $('#brands').append('<option value="' + obj[i].BrandID + '">' + obj[i].BrandName + '</option>');
                });
                $('.loader_cmn').hide();
                $('#brands').prop('disabled', false);

            }).fail(function (res) {
            });
        }

    });






    $('#display_alert').show();
    function load_session() {
        $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Login/set_accesskeys', type: 'post', async: false, cache: true, data: ''}).done(function (res)
        {
            setTimeout(2000);
        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
    }






    var msg = "<center><b>Please select brand</b></center>";
    if ($("#brands").val() === "") {
        $('#tw').html(msg);
        $('#fb').html(msg);
        $('#inst').html(msg);
        $('#yt').html(msg);
        $('#yelp').html(msg);
    } else {

        var brand_id = $.trim($("#brands").val());
        load_social_feeds(brand_id);
    }
    $("#brands").change(function () {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        var brand_id = $.trim(this.value);
        load_social_feeds(brand_id);

    });

    function hide_loader()
    {
        $('#loader_tw').hide();
        $('#loader_fb').hide();
        $('#loader_inst').hide();
        $('#loader_yt').hide();
    }

    function getChannelBrandlistJson(brand_id)
    {
        var channelBrandList;
        var facebookBrandName;
        var twitterBrandName;
        var youtubeBrandName;
        var instagramBrandName;
        var yelpBrandName;
        cblcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Login/getChannelBrand/' + brand_id, type: 'post', async: false, cache: true, data: '',
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (cblcurrentRequest != null) {
                    cblcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (firsttwcurrentRequest != null) {
                    firsttwcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (firstfbcurrentRequest != null) {
                    firstfbcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (firstigcurrentRequest != null) {
                    firstigcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (firstytcurrentRequest != null) {
                    firstytcurrentRequest.abort();
                }

                if (twcurrentRequest != null) {
                    twcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (fbcurrentRequest != null) {
                    fbcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (igcurrentRequest != null) {
                    igcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
                if (ytcurrentRequest != null) {
                    ytcurrentRequest.abort();
                }




            }
        }).done(function (res)
        {
            channelBrandList = JSON.parse(res);
            facebookBrandName = channelBrandList['FacebookChannel'];
            twitterBrandName = channelBrandList['TwitterChannel'];
            youtubeBrandName = channelBrandList['YoutubeChannel'];
            instagramBrandName = channelBrandList['InstagramChannel'];
            YelpBrandName = channelBrandList['YelpChannel'];

            $('#facebookchannel').val(facebookBrandName);
            console.log(facebookBrandName);
            $('#twitterchannel').val(twitterBrandName);
            console.log(twitterBrandName);
            $('#youtubechannel').val(youtubeBrandName);
            console.log(youtubeBrandName);
            $('#instagramchannel').val(instagramBrandName);
            console.log(instagramBrandName);
            $('#yelpchannel').val(YelpBrandName);
            console.log(yelpBrandName);


        }).fail(function (res) {
        });


    }

    function Twfeed(brand_name)
    {

        var indexCount = 2;//used to calls the all three month post
        $('#twContainer').scrollTop(0);
        $('#twContainer').perfectScrollbar('update');
        loader_show();
        // setTimeout(function wait() {
        twcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Twfeed/get_Twfeed/' + brand_name + '/' + indexCount, type: 'post', data: '',
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (twcurrentRequest != null) {
                    twcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
            }
        }).done(function (res)
        {
            if (res != null && res.trim() != '')
            {
                setcontent(res);
            }

        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
        //}, 1000);
    }

    function FirstTwfeed(brand_name)
    {
        var indexCount = 1; //used to calls the first three post
        $('#twContainer').scrollTop(0);
        $('#twContainer').perfectScrollbar('update');
        loader_show();
//        setTimeout(function wait() {
        firsttwcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Twfeed/get_Twfeed/' + brand_name + '/' + indexCount, type: 'post', data: ''}).done(function (res)
        {
            if (res != null && res.trim() != '')
            {
                setcontent(res);
                Twfeed(brand_name);
            }

        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
//        }, 1000);
    }

    function Fbfeed(brand_name)
    {
        // load_session();
        var indexCount = 2;
        $('#fbContainer').scrollTop(0);
        $('#fbContainer').perfectScrollbar('update');
        $('#loader_fb').show();
        //setTimeout(function wait() {
        fbcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Fbfeed/get_Fbfeed/' + brand_name + '/' + indexCount, type: 'post', data: '',
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (fbcurrentRequest != null) {
                    fbcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
            }
        }).done(function (res)
        {
            if (res != null && res.trim() != '')
            {
                $('#fb').html(res);
                $('#loader_fb').hide();
            }

        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
        //}, 1000);
    }
    function FirstFbfeed(brand_name)
    {
        // load_session();
        var indexCount = 1;
        $('#fbContainer').scrollTop(0);
        $('#fbContainer').perfectScrollbar('update');
        $('#loader_fb').show();
        //setTimeout(function wait() {
        firstfbcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Fbfeed/get_Fbfeed/' + brand_name + '/' + indexCount, type: 'post', data: '',
        }).done(function (res)
        {
            if (res != null && res.trim() != '')
            {
                $('#fb').html(res);
                $('#loader_fb').hide();
                Fbfeed(brand_name);
            }

        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
        //}, 1000);
    }

    function Instfeed(brand_name)
    {
        //load_session();
        var indexCount = 2;
        $('#instaContainer').scrollTop(0);
        $('#instaContainer').perfectScrollbar('update');
        $('#loader_inst').show();
        // setTimeout(function wait() {
        igcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Igfeed/get_Igfeed/' + brand_name + '/' + indexCount, type: 'post', data: '',
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (igcurrentRequest != null) {
                    igcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
            }
        }).done(function (res)
        {
            if (res != null && res.trim() != '')
            {
                $('#inst').html(res);
                $('#loader_inst').hide();
            }

        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
        //}, 1000);
    }

    function FirstInstfeed(brand_name)
    {
        //load_session();
        var indexCount = 1;
        $('#instaContainer').scrollTop(0);
        $('#instaContainer').perfectScrollbar('update');
        $('#loader_inst').show();
        // setTimeout(function wait() {
        firstigcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Igfeed/get_Igfeed/' + brand_name + '/' + indexCount, type: 'post', data: '',
        }).done(function (res)
        {
            if (res != null && res.trim() != '')
            {
                $('#inst').html(res);
                $('#loader_inst').hide();
                Instfeed(brand_name);
            }

        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
        //}, 1000);
    }


    function Ytfeed(brand_name)
    {
        //load_session();
        var indexCount = 2;
        $('#ytContainer').scrollTop(0);
        $('#ytContainer').perfectScrollbar('update');
        $('#loader_yt').show();
        //setTimeout(function wait() {
        ytcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Ytfeed/get_Ytfeed/' + brand_name + '/' + indexCount, type: 'post', data: '',
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (ytcurrentRequest != null) {
                    ytcurrentRequest.abort();
                }
            }
        }).done(function (res)
        {
            if (res != null && res.trim() != '')
            {
                $('#yt').html(res);
                $('#loader_yt').hide();
            }

        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
        // }, 1000);
    }

    function FirstYtfeed(brand_name)
    {
        //load_session();
        var indexCount = 1;
        $('#ytContainer').scrollTop(0);
        $('#ytContainer').perfectScrollbar('update');
        $('#loader_yt').show();
        //setTimeout(function wait() {
        firstytcurrentRequest = $.ajax({url: baseurl + 'Ytfeed/get_Ytfeed/' + brand_name + '/' + indexCount, type: 'post', data: '',
        }).done(function (res)
        {
            if (res != null && res.trim() != '')
            {
                $('#yt').html(res);
                $('#loader_yt').hide();
                Ytfeed(brand_name);
            }

        }).fail(function (res) {
        });
        // }, 1000);
    }



    function setcontent(res) {
        $('#tw').html(res);
        loader_hide();
    }

    function loader_show() {
        $('#loader_tw').show();
    }
    function loader_hide() {
        $('#loader_tw').hide();
    }




    function load_social_feeds(brand_id) {
        //load_session();
        getChannelBrandlistJson(brand_id);
        //load_session();
        //setTimeout(function wait() {
        $('#tw').html("");
        $('#fb').html("");
        $('#inst').html("");
        $('#yt').html("");
        $('#yelp').html("");
        //var brand_name = $.trim($("#brands").val());
        //alert('load method');
        if (brand_id !== "") {

            $(".chanel input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function ()
            {

                //alert("Id: " + $(this).attr("id") + " Value: " + $(this).val() + " Checked: " + $(this).is(":checked"));

                $exp = parseInt($(this).val());

                switch ($exp) {
                    case 1:
                        $('#twsection').show();
                        var twitterBrandName = $('#twitterchannel').val();
                        console.log('twitterBrandName-' + twitterBrandName);
                        FirstTwfeed(twitterBrandName);
                        // Twfeed(twitterBrandName); // Load Twitter
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $('#fbsection').show();
                        var facebookBrandName = $('#facebookchannel').val();
                        console.log('facebookBrandName-' + facebookBrandName);
                        FirstFbfeed(facebookBrandName);
                        // Fbfeed(facebookBrandName); // Load Facebook
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $('#instsection').show();
                        var instagramBrandName = $('#instagramchannel').val();
                        console.log('instagramBrandName-' + instagramBrandName);
                        FirstInstfeed(instagramBrandName); // Load Instagram
                        //Instfeed(instagramBrandName); // Load Instagram
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $('#ytsection').show();
                        var youtubeBrandName = $('#youtubechannel').val();
                        console.log('youtubeBrandName-' + youtubeBrandName);
                        FirstYtfeed(youtubeBrandName); //Load Youtube
                        //Ytfeed(youtubeBrandName); //Load Youtube
                        break;

                }



            });


        } else {

            $('#tw').html(msg);
            $('#fb').html(msg);
            $('#inst').html(msg);
            $('#yt').html(msg);
            $('#yelp').html(msg);
        }


    }





});
```

I am using Codeigniter framework for server script.ajax call request to my controller and controller all required API Libraries and send back HTML response back to ajax.

Please suggest,if i am missing anything.

Thanks,

Comment: Why `async: false` with `getChannelBrandlistJson()`? Also, have you heard of the [DRY](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don't_Repeat_Yourself) concept?

Comment: My api calling function using async: true which is default. i have set async: false for function because i want to set  some parameter value before ajax call made like brand name and session value etc.